# Ruby undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby

I know that this is a common question, but after reading through other stack overflow questions, I just don't get it.

Example:
I'm writing a least common multiple function for a range of numbers (Project Euler #5) and I can't figure out why one of these works while the other throws an error:

Works:

```
fact_list2 = fact_list2.reject {|i| i == reject1}
count2 = length2 - fact_list2.length()
```

Throws Error undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError):

```
count2 = length2 - fact_list2.reject! {|i| i == reject1}.length()
```

Above this I have a check that the fact_list2 is an array but it doesn't seem to make any difference.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Integer already has an [lcm method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-lcm).

Comment: Array also have a count method that might be useful for this kind of operation.

Comment: yes, I'm trying to learn ruby syntax by building my own lcm method.  Didn't know about the count method, so thanks for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reject!` only returns the array if changes were made, otherwise it returns `nil`.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21

Assuming you need `fact_list2` to permanently reject those values, you may need to keep it to two lines, though you can still shorten it using `reject!`:

```
fact_list2.reject! {|i| i == reject1}
count2 = length2 - fact_list2.length()
```